# Switches gets unreachable then reachable automatically

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, switching

I am currently facing an issue that for a remote site few switches gets unreachable and then reachable after sometime (could be 1 - 2 days) from a specific IP of a subnet whereas always reachable from another IP of the same subnet.

Scenario:
There is a remote site connected to our main location through WAN link which is terminated at Core router at site. There is a core switch behind router and other switches are behind the core router. Reachablity from NMS server goes down whereas those switches are accessible from another server with an IP address from the same subnet. After some time switches becomes reachable and gets unreachable again.

Following is the output from both servers:

From Server A

```
C:\Users>tracert 11.11.0.123

Tracing route to 11.11.0.156 over a maximum of 30 hops
  1     5 ms     7 ms     3 ms  172.16.9.1
  2     7 ms     3 ms     7 ms  172.16.57.2
  3    18 ms    19 ms    19 ms  172.16.30.218
  4    19 ms    19 ms    19 ms  11.11.0.123
Trace complete.
```

From Server B [NMS]

```
[root@localhost ~]# tracepath 11.11.0.156
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  gateway                                               0.591ms
 1:  gateway                                               1.995ms
 2:  172.16.57.2                                          2.033ms
 3:  172.16.57.2                                          1.862ms pmtu 1476
 3:  172.16.30.218                                       13.858ms
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
 6:  no reply
^C
```

//////////From switch////////////

```
HOUSINGOFFICE#traceroute 172.16.9.101

Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to Server B [NMS]

  1  *  *  * 
  2  *  *  * 
  3  *  *  * 

Tracing the route to Server A

  1 11.11.0.1 0 msec 0 msec 0 msec
  2 172.16.30.217 17 msec 9 msec 16 msec
  3 172.16.57.1 17 msec 9 msec 17 msec
  4  *  *  * [Trace is completed]
```

Following is the trace from switch which is reachable to NMS:
Switch to Server B [NMS]

```
Tracing the route to Server B

  1 11.11.0.1 4 msec 4 msec 0 msec
  2 172.16.30.217 12 msec 12 msec 12 msec
  3 172.16.57.1 12 msec 16 msec 12 msec
  4 172.16.9.101 16 msec 16 msec 16 msec
```

From Server B to switch

```
[root@localhost ~]# tracepath 11.11.0.111
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  gateway                                               2.250ms
 1:  gateway                                               4.085ms
 2:  172.16.57.2                                          1.753ms
 3:  172.16.57.2                                          2.580ms pmtu 1476
 3:  172.16.30.218                                       14.146ms
 4:  11.11.0.111                                           19.797ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1476 hops 4 back 4
```

Network diagram (from comment):
[image: Network diagram]

Comment: This kind of issue looks like a  MAC address issue or VLAN misconfiguration. Look at the ARP table of the router  used by the switches as a gateway. Do you see the MAC address of the switch? Is it in the correct VLAN? A network diagram would help, it is much more readable than a textual description.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Access switches are using ip of core switch as gateway and core switch is using IP. Also ARP is completed on both core router and switch and they are all part of VLAN1. See attached n/w diagram.

Comment: N/w Diagram: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5nq4wv4puexj2k/Diagram.png?dl=1

Comment: You should include the network device models and configurations. At the very least for the router and core switch.

Answer (score 1):

When a device behind the switch in question is reachable and the switch is reachable locally, this can practically only be a routing issue.

Double check the default gateway on the switches in question (static or DHCP) and that the switch can ping the router (or vice versa). Also check possibly involved firewall/VPN rules (I'm assuming "remote" means accessed through a VPN link).

Less likely scenarios are ARP cache poisoning (on switch or core router), a rogue DHCP server changing the switches' default gateway, route manipulations on the switches through SNMP, ... These may need to be ruled out one by one while the problem occurs. A simple traceroute doesn't produce enough information.

Comment: We have checked default gateway on the switches and it is static and yes both switches and router can ping each other.